# WWDR certificate expired

Tags: ios, certificate, signing

I am signing iOS Apps in development and production.

However I am unable to sign new builds since the WWDR intermediate certificate just expired (February 14, 2016).

I have installed the new WWDR intermediate certificate (expiry on February 7, 2023) after the expiry of the previous one. The Apple support page says that current signing certificates do not need to be regenerated as they will work with both the expired and the new certificate.
Link: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

I am still unable to sign builds even though I have installed the new WWDR intermediate certificate.

Is my only option to revoke and re-generate my certificates?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Keychain Access. View -> Show Expired Certificates.
Delete expired certificate.

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-gen your certificates. It's just that in Keychain Access you need to also drag a copy of the new cert into the system folder. I had the same issue but this got me back up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else reaches this thread here - deleting might not be enough - please look at the chosen answer in here (it has helped me): [Unable to delete Apple WWDRC Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511314/unable-to-delete-apple-wwdrc-certificate?noredirect=1#comment58849071_35511314)