# Unable to delete Apple WWDRC Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

Recently Apple [posted an announcement](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/), according to this the intermediate certificate got expired on Feb 14th and has to be downloaded manually and should replace the older expired certificate in the System keychain.

I am unable to delete the existing certificate from the Keychain, leave alone importing the new one. How do I delete the old one and replace it with the new one?
[image]

Steps already followed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35406327/1781918

Comment: I have the same exact issue... did you ever get to solve it? I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve this issue. Check my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to resolve this issue.

First, I [enabled the root user in my system](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204012)

> #### OS X Lion (10.7) and later
>
> 1. From the Apple menu choose System Preferences.
> 2. From the View menu choose Users & Groups.
> 3. Click the lock and authenticate as an administrator account.
> 4. Click Login Options.
> 5. Click the "Edit" or "Join" button at the bottom right.
> 6. Click the "Open Directory Utility" button.
> 7. Click the lock in the Directory Utility window.
> 8. Enter an administrator account name and password, then click OK.
> 9. Choose Enable Root User from the Edit menu.
> 10. Enter the root password you wish to use in both the Password and Verify fields, then click OK.

In the terminal, I logged in as root user

> 1. Open Terminal
> 2. Type `su` and then press Enter
> 3. Enter the password you just set for the root user above. This will log you in as the root user
> 4. Type `cd /Library` and then press Enter
> 5. Type `chmod 777 Keychains/`. This will change folder permissions for the Keychains folder
> 6. Now open the `Keychain Access` App and delete the `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` certificate from the
>      `System` keychain
> 7. Import the [renewed Intermediate certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) in your `login` keychain
> 8. Close the Keychain Access app

Although, the certificate which you just deleted will appear again in the System keychain but all your other Developer and Distribution certificates will become valid again.

Make sure you set back the Keychains folder permission back to 755

`chmod 755 Keychains/`

Comment: This is a great answer and should get lots and lots of up-votes!! I've been struggling with this forever now - thanks. Apple really did a number on us with this one...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "Operation not permitted". So you don't have the necessary access right. To solve this click on the lock in the upper left corner of the keychain and enter your password.

[image: Lock in the keychain window]

After you entered your credentials you should be able to delete the old certificate.

Comment: To perform any action in the Keychain, this is the first thing which needs ti be done. It prompts for user credentials if the keychain is locked. No, this is not the solution

Comment: So your lock is open like on my screenshot? Have you tried to open the new certificate in the keychain to overwrite the old one?

Comment: It shows an error "An error occured. Unable to import 'Apple  worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority'. Error: 100001" when I try to overwrite it by dragging the new certificate file. Yes, the lock is open

Comment: I think it's a permission problem. Do you have administration rights on your system?

Comment: It's my personal system. I am the only administrator of the system

Comment: Sorry. I have no other idea, where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete the certificate by first viewing the `expired certificate` in **system keychain** and then deleting them. Then rechecking if the certificate was deleted from the **certificate keychain** as well. Then downloading new certificate and installing them. This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services) you.

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7357200?start=0&tstart=0

As you can see in the above link, some keys cannot be deleted while the OS is running in full mode, and you need to boot in recovery mode.